# Can you create and destroy pthreads inside operator overloading function

Tags: c++, multithreading, operator-overloading

I am trying to overload the * operator to use for matrix multiplication. It must be multithreaded using pthreads. I have never done multithreading before, and I am really struggling. If possible I would like to create and destroy the pthreads within the function(so the only place pthreads appear is within the function).

Here is my Matrix Class:

```
class Matrix
{
private:
    int numRows_;
    int numColumns_;
    std::vector<double> data_;

public:
    Matrix();
    Matrix(Matrix const& matrix_objext);
    Matrix(int numRows, int numColumns);
    Matrix(int numRows, int numColumns, std::vector<double> data);
    Matrix(std::string importFilePath);
    ~Matrix();

    int get_numRows();
    int get_numColumns();
    std::vector<double> get_data();
    void set_numRows(int);
    void set_numColumns(int);
    void set_data(std::vector<double>);

    Matrix operator*(Matrix x);
    Matrix operator*(int x);
    Matrix operator+(Matrix x);
    Matrix operator-(Matrix x);
    Matrix operator^(int exp);
    Matrix operator-();
    Matrix operator=(Matrix x);
    bool operator==(Matrix x);

    Matrix MultiplySlow(Matrix x);
    Matrix Transpose();
    void ExportToFile(std::string);
    std::string to_string();

};
```

This is the function I am struggling with:

```
Matrix Matrix::operator*(Matrix x){
    pthread_t thread;
    int rc;
    rc = pthread_create(&thread, NULL, MultiplySlow, x)
}
```

The MultiplySlow function is not intended to be used only for this overloaded operator, so if it needs to be changed I would have to make a new multiplication function.

Here is the MultiplySlow function just in case:

```
Matrix Matrix::MultiplySlow(Matrix x){
    Matrix mat;
    mat.numColumns_=numColumns_;
    mat.numRows_=numRows_;
    mat.data_.resize(numRows_*numColumns_);
    if(numColumns_ != x.numRows_){
        std::cout << "The number of columns of the 1st matrix must equal the number of rows of the 2nd matrix." << std::endl;
    }
    for(int i=0; i<numRows_;i++){
        for(int j=0; j<x.numColumns_;j++){
            double sum =0.0;
            for(int k=0; k<x.numRows_; k++){
                sum = sum + data_[i * numColumns_ + k] * x.data_[k * x.numColumns_ +j];
            }
            mat.data_[i * mat.numColumns_ + j] = sum;
        }
    }
    return mat;
}
```

Please help!!

Comment: You need to be very careful with threads, as you can introduce a data race if the main thread is modifying the data while the background thread is doing the multiplication.  You need to synchronize all the usage, or it's going to fail badly, but locking for every operation can also be high overhead that you might not want to pay.  You might want the user to decide if it should be processed in a thread instead of choosing for them in core matrix operators.  You also need to consider how the main thread will know when the worker thread has finished.

Comment: Use `std::thread`-s

Answer (score 2):

There are a few problems here:

1. `pthread_create()` returns 0 or 1 depending on success or failure (not a matrix).
2. The function that is spawn by the thread is supposed to return `void *` and receive a `void *` (not a matrix)
3. Spawning another thread to do the actual multiplication hinders efficiency. It doesn’t help it. So, why are you doing this?

My suggestions are

1. Look into C++ threads
2. look into C++ `async` calls
3. Think about how to divide the matrix multiplication into independent components, so multi-threading could help efficiency.